# Is just one variable count as minimum sum-of-products?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Let's say I have an expression in a form $(a\cdot b \cdot -c) + (a \cdot b \cdot c) + (a \cdot -b \cdot c \cdot d)$ and I am asked to find the minimum sum-of-products using algebraic manipulation. After the algebraic manipulation steps if I can simplify and ended up with c (c is just an example it is probably not what you will get in this case if you simplify it  - this is not the question since I can't post the real question due to plagiarism) as a result is it still in the form of sum-of-manipulation? I imagine it is but I just want to be make sure.

Edit: sum-of-product -> $(a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c \cdot d) + (a \cdot d)$

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense without more context. What does it mean to "find the minimum sum-of-products"? Minimum in what sense? How did you end up with just $c$ as a result? (Certainly if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are numbers, then your expression is just equal to $-(a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d)$, since the first two terms in the sum cancel. If they are *not* numbers, you should definitely explain what they are!) What is "the form of sum-of-manipulation"? These are not standard terms, so you should explain what you mean.

Comment: I am sorry that the question was not very clear. I tried to expand a bit but I don't know whether it will help or not since I am really not sure about the exact limitations of the sum-of-products. And the expression I gave as an example and the answer c are just examples I didn't really simplified the expression. It just meant to show that if there is such an expression and at the end of simplification process end up with just one of the variable. And sum-of-products must be a standard term isn't

Comment: Plagiarism is when you present someone else's work as your own. If you give proper credit, then you won't be plagiarizing. There may be some other reason not to, but plagiarism is not it.